# RoR: retrieve values from database and show in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was trying to count my objects and to show the number in view by doing something like this:

show.html.erb:

```
 <%Files.where(defined:"yes").count do |number|%>
    <%= number %>
    <% end %>
```

But it shows nothing. Where is the problem?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.count` returns an integer value, not an array, so you can't iterate over it. Just do this:

```
<%= Files.where(defined: "yes").count %>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using `<%= ` and not just `<% `?